# How to show real time difference between timestamps in two different zones with SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone, timezone-offset

This query returns 0

```sql
SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'PST' 
      - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AS td
  FROM dual
```

How can I make it to actually show the real difference in time? For example, in this case I want to see a difference of -8 hours.

In this example I used CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but I have a real use case where I have timestamps in two different time zones. And I want the real time difference between those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the values to a `TIMESTAMP` without a time zone:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'PST' AS TIMESTAMP)
       - CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS TIMESTAMP)
       as td
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

> | TD |
> | --- |
> | -000000000 08:00:00.000000 |

Or, considering times around the DST boundary:

```sql
-- Times around the DST boundary.
WITH times (t) AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-03-14 09:30:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2021-03-14 10:30:00 UTC' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT t As t_utc,
       t AT TIME ZONE 'PST8PDT' AS t_pstpdt,
       (CAST(t AT TIME ZONE 'PST8PDT' AS TIMESTAMP)
        - CAST(t AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS TIMESTAMP)) AS td
FROM   times
```

Outputs:

> | T_UTC | T_PSTPDT | TD |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-03-14 09:30:00.000000000 UTC | 2021-03-14 01:30:00.000000000 PST8PDT | -000000000 08:00:00.000000 |
> | 2021-03-14 10:30:00.000000000 UTC | 2021-03-14 03:30:00.000000000 PST8PDT | -000000000 07:00:00.000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1aba6b288fa9966e8bec1d100c5ae503)*

Comment: That is brilliant! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to find the time difference between the time zones. (This is not what the title says; the title is misleading.)

If so, then you don't need to reference `current_timestamp`, or anything of the kind.

Since you are comparing PST to UTC, this is the same as finding the UTC offset of PST. This makes the problem even easier. (In the general case, you can find the offset of both time zones and subtract; in your example, the offset of UTC to itself is zero, obviously).

```
select to_char(to_timestamp_tz('PST', 'tzr'), 'tzh:tzm') as pst_offset
from   dual;


PST_OFFSET
----------
-08:00
```

Comment: This will find the time zone difference from PST to UTC at midnight at the start of the current month (since you are using `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` without specifying all the date-time components) which may not be what the OP was after. This may give an unexpected result if you use it in the same month after a daylight-savings change when the result returned is before the daylight-savings change rather than after. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d245c8838294d118efda4d9d591a428d)

Comment: @MT0 - PST is "standard" time zone, it does not have a DST feature. The question, as posed by the OP, only makes sense for such time zones. If DST is in play, then giving a timestamp (without time zone) and asking for the time difference between two time zones is ambiguous; the timestamp may exist in one time zone but not in the other, for example (if it's skipped as one time zone goes from summer to winter time, but the other time zone doesn't have DST, or has DST on a different date). These are all things I chose not to discuss since they didn't seem relevant.

Comment: @MT0 - in your solution, if you want to consider PDT instead of PST (for example `'America/Los_Angeles`), try your query if all your setup is in UTC (meaning current timestamp, etc.), and you use your query when current time is 2:30 AM on the day PDT goes from winter to summer time. You will get an error.